# Not getting nginx and gunicorn running in Docker container

Tags: nginx, docker, gunicorn

I am new to Docker and trying my best to figure out every bit, but seriously struggle on starting gunicorn and nginx with my Dockerfile.
Whenever I add the last four lines, the container won't boot and also fails with no error message at all.

```
FROM python:3.9-buster

EXPOSE 80

RUN apt update
RUN apt upgrade
RUN apt install nginx python3 python3-pip git swig python3-dev build-essential libmagic-dev -y
RUN apt install ffmpeg -y
RUN mkdir /opt/xxx
RUN git clone https://xxx:xxx@github.com/xxx/backend.git /opt/xxx/
RUN mkdir /root/d12f
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
COPY .env /opt/xxx/xxx/.env
RUN pip3 install -r /opt/xxx/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install gunicorn
RUN git clone https://xxx:xxx@github.com/xxx/configs.git /root/configs/
RUN cp /root/configs/nginx/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/.
RUN mkdir /var/log/celery/
CMD /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
CMD /usr/local/bin/celery -A xxx --workdir /opt/xxx worker --loglevel=INFO -P prefork &
CMD /usr/local/bin/celery -A xxx --workdir /opt/xxx beat --schedule=/tmp/celerybeat-schedule --loglevel=INFO
CMD /usr/bin/gunicorn --chdir /opt/xxx --conf xxx:gunicorn_conf xxx:wsgi
```

The build works as expected but running with docker run -p 80:80 xxx:latest is not.

Answer (score 1):

`Dockerfile` isn't a shell script. There could be only one `CMD` instruction per `Dockerfile` ([reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)). Forking daemons like `nginx` which switch to the background by default will cause a container to terminate immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What's the best practice to start these daemons/processes?

Comment: The best practice is to start these daemons/processes in the foreground. Use a separate container for each service/process.